# Reading memory from ".exe" + offset?

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, memory, offset

I'm using WinAPI's `ReadProcessMemory()` to read some "hidden" information from a game.

I've used Cheat Engine to find out the static pointers, but I don't know how to read from them.
Cheat Engine gives me a pointer to something like this: `"mygame.exe"+1C50`

I'm really new to WinAPI, how do I convert `"mygame.exe"+1C50` to an address that I can read with `ReadProcessMemory()`?

**EDIT:** I tried simplifying the problem, but I guess I should've just given the full code in the first place.
So I'm working with static addresses and multi level pointers here, but I'm still stuck with getting the base address or w/e.

Here's the full code and [a picture of my cheat engine address](http://pbrd.co/11uVjjf):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

using namespace std;

HANDLE GetProcessHandle(const char *procName);

int main()
{
    const char *procName = "prism3d.exe";
    HANDLE hProc = GetProcessHandle(procName);
    if (hProc) {

     /* This works if I use the dynamic address (f.e. 0x02C2C4DC),
        but it changes every time I restart the game.
        I need to use the static address (prism3d.exe+A1C) to get
        the dynamic address for my "nuke".
      */
        float nuke;
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)0x02C2C4DC, &nuke, 4, 0);
        cout << nuke;

    }
    CloseHandle(hProc);
    return 0;
}

HANDLE GetProcessHandle(const char *procName)
{
    HANDLE hProc = NULL;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe32)) {
        do {
            if (!strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, procName)) {
                hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
                break;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe32));
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    return hProc;
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Here's how I tried reading the value of my nuke, but it gives me random numbers, different every time I restart the game (sometimes it's `0`, sometimes `324324324`, etc...):

```
if (hProc) [

    DWORD baseAddr = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(procName) + 0xA1C50; // also tried this with GetModuleHandle(NULL)
    DWORD mainAddr;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)(baseAddr + 0x111C), &mainAddr, 4, 0);

    // Nuke
    float nuke;
    DWORD nukeAddr;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)(mainAddr + 0x48), &nukeAddr, 4, 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)nukeAddr, &nuke, 4, 0);
    cout << nuke;
}
```

Comment: You need to locate the base-address of "game.dll", and then add 1C50.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base offset is generally the start of the module in memory, you can get this with `GetModuleHandle` (the address this returns is the start of the PE in memory). I say generally because some conventions define the base relative to the start of the code section, which you then need to read from the PE.

you can do something such as the following:

```
UINT_PTR addr = (UINT_PTR)GetModuleHandle("game.dll") + 0x1C50;
ReadProcessMemory(hProc,(void*)addr,pBuffer,nSize,&BytesRead);
```

The above only works if you are running in the address space of the process you are targeting (via dll injection), to do this via a remote process (as your example shows) you need to enumerate to process modules to get a valid handle to the module you are interested in.

MSDN has an example of that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), refactoring it a bit, you can create a function that checks against the name and return the `HMODULE` if it matches, casting this will give you the module base address.

Comment: Not working, it's just giving me some weird ass numbers, not the correct addresses :/ I edited the question, I already have `.exe` static pointer

Comment: @SkamahOne have you checked whether the address CE reports is file relative or code section relative? and what exactly are the "weird" numbers?

Comment: Nope, how do I check that...? I have a pointer with value of `"mygame.exe" + 1C50` which points to an other address, I'm trying to get the "other address". And just some huge integers, `17512325403` etc.

Comment: @SkamahOne that "huge integer" is the address, ReadProcessMemory will only do one level of indirection, so you will need to use it multiple times to follow the pointers

Comment: @SkamahOne: Just realised you aren't running in the address space of the process, so GetModuleHandle will fail, see my update

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer.  I use CE as well, and it gives address relative to a module.  I always use GetModuleHandle() + offset as Necrolis suggests, but I do so from an injected DLL (also as Necrolis suggests).  This answer is correct; Skamah One is not running in the same address space, which Necrolis also addresses.