# ReadProcessMemory reads all 0s in a process memory

Tags: c++, winapi, readprocessmemory

I am trying to write a process memory scanner that scans for nonzero values in the memory:

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
char* addr = 0;
dtype readVal = 0;
while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) {  // HANDLE hProc is defined earlier
  if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mbi.RegionSize; i += sizeof(readVal)) {
            BOOL ret = ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (char*) mbi.BaseAddress + i, &readVal, sizeof(readVal), 0);
            printf("ReadProcessMemory returns %d\n", ret); // returns 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
            if (readVal != 0) {
                printf("Found a good value!");
                system("pause");
            }
        }
    }
    addr += mbi.RegionSize;
}
```

I tried it on `chrome.exe` and the scanner found a ton of nonzero values. But when I tried it on a game process that comes with an anticheat it fails to work, `ReadProcessMemory` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` in each call of `ReadProcessMemory`. The handle `hProc` had no problem attaching to the game process and the correct PID was found. Why is that and how can we increase our privilege to bypass the anticheat?

Comment: You're just asking because you're impressed and want to do the same thing yourself, right?

Comment: `readVal` is uninitialized, and you are not checking the return value of `ReadProcessMemory()` for success before evaluating `readVal`, so any result of using `readVal` is *indeterminate*.

Comment: Add error checking and let the error values tell you what's wrong

Comment: @RemyLebeau Assuming `dtype` is a POD (which it probably is), that's not a problem. ReadProcess is supposed to write/initialize it, so as long as `ReadProcess` succeeds, reading from `readVal` is not undefined.

Comment: @sba The code in question never evaluates, whether reading from a particular memory location is safe. Thus, the result is **always** undefined. The fact that there is a possibility for the code to not fail doesn't mean the code weren't broken. It is broken exactly for the reason Remy pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964666/reading-memory-from-exe-offset), you need to [enumerate all modules for a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to get a valid handle to the module you are interested in. Then you can use `ReadProcessMemory` like this running as an Administrator to read the multilevel pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

DWORD_PTR dwGetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwProcID, TCHAR *szModuleName);
    
int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Game");
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Cannot find window." << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD procID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);
        DWORD_PTR ModuleBaseAddress = 0;
        ModuleBaseAddress = dwGetModuleBaseAddress(procID, _T("Game.exe"));

        if (procID == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Cannot find process.";
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(-1);
        }
        else {
            while (true)
            {
                DWORD temp;
                ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)(ModuleBaseAddress + 0x43021C), &temp, sizeof(temp), NULL);
                ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)(temp + 0xAC), &temp, sizeof(temp), NULL);
                int curhp;
                ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)(temp + 0x4C), &curhp, sizeof(curhp), NULL);
                cout << "Current HP: "  << curhp << endl;
                Sleep(100);
                system("CLS");
            }
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}

DWORD_PTR dwGetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwProcID, TCHAR *szModuleName)
{
    DWORD_PTR dwModuleBaseAddress = 0;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, dwProcID);
    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32;
        ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32))
        {
            do
            {
                if (_tcsicmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, szModuleName) == 0)
                {
                    dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
    return dwModuleBaseAddress;
}
```

For more details, you may research from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

A trimmed down version of your code does approximately this:

```cpp
dtype readVal;
if (readVal != 0) {
    printf("Found a good value!");
    system("pause");
}
```

There's a (probably) uninitialized value (`readVal`), some code with a code path that doesn't alter the value, followed by a read access. Doing so has no specified behavior. Its behavior is thus implied to be undefined.

To fix your code you'll need to make two changes:

- `readVal` needs to be initialized, and reset in the innermost loop. Though without knowing what data type `readVal` is, it's impossible to know whether it is or isn't initialized. That's left as an exercise.
- [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) can fail. It reports failure by returning `FALSE`. You will need to check for failure, and optionally call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) if you need extended error information.

---

> Why is that and how can we bypass the anticheat?

We don't know, since you decided to keep vital information private (e.g. the specific name and version of the target). Bypassing software protection is designed to be difficult. Spend a decade in binary exploitation and you *might* be prepared to come up with a way. Not something Stack Overflow can help you with.

Comment: I have checked the return value of `ReadProcessMemory`, it gives 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`) in all of its function calls. How can we increase our privilege to access the pages?

Comment: That would require that you first understand how the protection is implemented. There are many different ways a process can protect itself from having its memory read. There is no generic answer to this. You're going to have to research what the target application is doing. Learning to cheat well is frequently **a lot** harder than learning how to play well.